# Git checkout latest branch and go back to latest commit

Tags: git

I am working on my project, I made two commits but did not pushed them yet. During this time other people from my team made some changes and pushed them.

Now I want to pull the latest branch version with all the work from my team, play with it a bit and return back to my latest commit without the extra work that other people from my team did.

How do I do that?

Comment: always use the feature branch to work and if someone did any commit in the master branch rebase its change to your feature branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git fetch origin develop && git checkout origin/develop`

You'll be in detached head. Once you are done:

`git checkout develop`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your commits are on `master` branch.

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git branch my_branch`
3. `git reset HEAD^^`
4. `git fetch; git rebase origin/master`

Explanation:

1. Make sure you have your local `master` checked out
2. Create a new branch called `my_branch`, that for now is the same as master
3. Rollback your local `master` two commits back
4. Fetch changes from `origin`, and fast forward your local `master` to same commits

At the end of this you will have `master` with the work from your team, and `my_branch` with your work. Hope it helps!